# Is it possible to iterate through particles in python?

Tags: python, particles

Is it possible to iterate through particles like vertices of a mesh, to kill some?
I'm trying to remove overlapping particles of still droplets.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but I do know that each particle does have it's own unique Index number -- I found it in the "Particle Info" node's Index value. I hope this helps.

Comment: You might also be able to figure out some more useful information from this post on the [Particle Info Node](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2012/05/particle-info-node/)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible in the current release, but it seems like [it will be in new releases](https://developer.blender.org/rBeee0f75b1f58e4b7b5f5745655c17039331a8f33) (I think).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is to some extent.

```
ps = obj.particle_systems[particle_sys]
particles = ps.particles

# on large objects list comprehension seems to be slower than index
# and . dotted access is also a slowing factor
for i in range(len(particles)):
    # alive_state
    # angular_velocity
    # birth_time
    # die_time
    # hair_keys
    # is_exist
    # is_visible
    # lifetime
    pt = particles[i]
    if pt.is_exist and pt.alive_state == 'ALIVE':
        # do something... add_loc(pt.location[:])
        ...
    # prev_angular_velocity
    # prev_location
    # prev_rotation
    # prev_velocity
    # rotation
    # size
    # velocity
```

`pt.location` would give the coordinate. The Particles API seems to be slightly under-developed, but perhaps this info will help you.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but wondering: when I do pt.is_visible, I get a warning that "is_visible" is read-only. Is this always the case, or is there something you need to do in order to be able to edit this parameter?

Comment: i'd like to think i tried `.is_visible` before suggesting that, but am not sure anymore.

Comment: the only property I routinely used for experimentation was `pt.location` "out of sight out of mind", also `.size` might be useful

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm running into issues with setting particle parameters using Python code. I've used .location and .size to change those values for specific particles, and when I print them I see the new values I specified... but in the 3-D viewer nothing changes. Is there something I need to do for my changes to reflect in the model visualization? One thing I noticed is that changing between Object and Particle Edit mode causes the particle parameters to revert to their starting values. Many thanks in advance for any insight you might have!

Comment: unfortunately the particle API is weak sauce. One thing that you need to do is to trigger an update (to scene..i think). Rotating 3d view after passing a new value to a particle is enough to show what i mean. However in relation to doing this for many particles in a scriptable way you may want to add an event handler to trigger that update. (kind of outside of the scope of the comment section...).

Comment: so per frame, set all the particle properties..and then before rendering the frame you update the scene.

Comment: I'll give that a try! I've used a couple of Python commands to update the scene after updating the particle properties, and I've used the UI to try to trigger an update (switching between render and material mode in the 3-D View pane, for example, and changing the current animation frame), though nothing has worked so far. Maybe rotating the 3-D view will work? It's worth a try—thanks for the suggestion!