# Blender Scripting Particles

Tags: scripting, particles

I recently found out about the particles systems in blender and I was wondering if I could receive the particles' locations or script its path. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-particles-in-python